# Check in powershell permission string is valid

Tags: powershell, acl

I try to implement a script which changes folder structure permission depending on some conditions. So far I set permissions with

```
    $accessRule = New-Object  System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$($group.Name)", @("$($group.Value.rights)"), "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "$($group.Value.type)")
    $aclFolder.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    Set-Acl $folder $aclFolder
```

So far it works. But the script currently assumes, that a permission does exist. It it does not, the AddAccessRule command throws and error.

Is there any way recognize a permission exists?

Comment: Maybe I should give a more detailed description:

$($group.Name) could be a string for a group which does not exist. When I apply a group/user which does not exist, it will throw a error. I want catch this error by first checking, the string does exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get-Acl $folder` to read the current ACL and to verify if there are any permissions applied already.